# How can I create a type whose value can only be within a valid range?

Tags: f#

**How can I create a type whose value can only be within a valid range?**

Most statically typed languages provide numeric types in which each type supports a range of values.

An [int](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx) is an example of such type.

To support the following:

> Make illegal states unrepresentable

**How can I create a type such that a value assignment that's out-of-range results in an error at compile-time?**

For example:
Type PositiveInteger // range is 0 to 2,147,483,647

**UPDATE**

I attempted this:

```
type PositiveInteger = private PInt of int with
    static member FromInt i =
       if i <= 0 then failwith "out of range" else PInt i

let isSuccessful = 
    PInt -1
```

However, the above code still compiles when I want it to throw "out of range" at compile time.
Is it fair to say that this isn't supported for compile time?

Comment: Well in the specific case F# does have unsigned integers.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @JohnPalmer ~~`uint32` includes `0u`~~ though ;) ... oops .. `PositiveInteger` should include `0` ... well I guess my understanding of math clashed a bit with the definition here ... sorry :(

Comment: for the last bit then yes you are right - this is still runtime - but using a ADT / peano style is not (you cannot represent even `0` with that) - the question is how much work to you want to put into your types (you will get to F#'s limits quite fast) and what really makes sense

Comment: Take a look at [F# Math (III.) - Defining custom numeric types](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-custom-numeric.aspx/) by Tomas Petricek

Answer (score 6, accepted):

let's keep at this example (and extend it to mean *positive p <=> p > 0*)

You can always go and use some math (here using slight modification of the  [peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Peano_axioms) to define positive natural numbers):

```
type PositiveInteger =
   | One
   | Succ of PositiveInteger
```

which would have a greater range

of course this is a bit hard to use:

```
let one = One
let two = Succ one
...
let rec add a b =
     match (a,b) with
     | (One, b)    -> Succ b
     | (Succ a, b) -> Succ (add a b)
```

and this is usually not efficient enough (although it is commonly used on the type-level ... if the language supports it)

---

So probably most people would use the *fail-fast* approach with some kind of *smart constructor*:

```
type PositiveInteger = private PInt of int with
    static member FromInt i =
       if i <= 0 then failwith "out of range" else PInt i
```

---

this one should compile too if you misslike the `with`:

```
type PositiveInteger = 
    private | PInt of int
    static member FromInt i =
        if i <= 0 then failwith "out of range" else PInt i
```

Comment: Thanks Carsten, I am having trouble compiling your example. "Unexpected keyword 'static' in definition".

Comment: sorry missed a `with`

Comment: Hmmm... The following compiles when I want it to throw "out of range" at compile time.
Is it fair to say that this isn't supported for compile time?

Please see update...

Comment: yes of course the *smart constructor* thing happens at runtime - it's quite hard to really pull down everything to the compiler as F# is not nearly expressive enough for this - if you are interested in this kind of stuff then you should look into dependent types - GOQ, AGDA, IDRIS and more and more Haskell to name a few well-known languages that support far more than F# in this manner

Comment: btw: there is [F*](https://fstar-lang.org/) also ... but (shame on my) I never really looked into this

Answer (score 1):

I'm typically using the static function that returns instance of `Result<T, Error>`, exceptions are really not a good pattern.